# Firebase Realtime Db: device cache strategy for large piece of data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-room

My big task in general looks like this: I have timeline data in Realtime DB, splitted to upcoming days. There are 5 upcoming days, include current day. Each day timeline takes about 50MB. The challenge is to have local cache in a phone for all timeline days.

Android Firebase persistance mode supports up to 100MB local cache size, so this way looks like not sutable. Now I'm look at local DB (Room) to keep timeline in. So, what the best approach to get such large piece of data (5×50MB) from Realtime DB? I know I can use just `get()`, but it is possible mobile internet connection could be slow or even broken for some pesiod. Any thoughts?

Comment: maybe some implementation with a work manager

Comment: What are those 50MB composed of? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo this data is structured and not compressed

Comment: No, no, what do those 50MB include? Only JSON data?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, just json, no byte-data

Comment: Why do you want to use Firebase Realtime Database for this? It sounds like the data is pretty static (maybe aside from the current day), so did you consider using Cloud Storage or Firebase Hosting for those files?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen 1. timeline data is not static and could be updated during a day, so I will had to bring those updates to mobile side 2. Each timeline day contains a lot of trips inside, so when user chose a trip, my mobile app should subscribe the trip and get realtime trip updates

Comment: Still worth considering if RTDB is the right tool for this. If most client will be synchronizing regularly, then most of the time they'll be downloading a small subset of the 250MB and it might work. If you expect many clients to sync less regularly, then they'd be downloading a basically immutable blob from Firebase for all past days - and there are cheaper mediums to download a blob from than from RTDB.